# AWS Lambda function to modify new files and add modified file into another directory

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have raw csv file in directory A in AWS and I want to call AWS Lambda to modify the raw csv file and place an edited csv file in directory B in AWS. The AWS Lambda function that I'm trying to create is that whatever new raw csv file added into directory A will trigger the function to create a modified file in directory B. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: What did you try? Any lambda code? Why it does not work?

Answer (score 0):

**S3 Trigger [lambda] Functions** can do the job after a file has been uploaded to an S3 bucket/directory. Follow [this AWS tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example.html) and let us know if your code is still not working.